# Unable to create database due to "not having permissions" even though I have created databases before

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was doing a project for my education when I could not merge datasets together in Google Colab due to not having enough ram to do so, not wanting to pay I decided to try doing the merging in SQL, download the result and upload it back into Google Colab for me to use. Using the same connection I always used during school time, I created a new query tab and tried to create a new database to upload my tables in. However, I was not allowed to do so and failed every time despite me changing the names each time. Why was it working before and not anymore?

[Screenshot of what I've entered and the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D7ts.png)

CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;

Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'Jovan Tan'@'%' to database 'test'

This occurs regardless of what name I've given to the database.